# How to dynamically bind a custom AngularJS modal?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, modal-dialog, model-binding

For an educational side-project I am working on, I want to avoid using AngularJS Material Design, UI Bootstrap, or any custom libraries that provide modal functionality.

However, I've hit a snag.  I've created a service that is supposed to manage and dynamically create modals.  It provides an `open` function that accepts a spec object, which it then reproduces in the DOM.

**What this code actually does:**
1. The modal is correctly appended to the DOM.
2. The modal controller's `$onInit` function fires.

**What this code does not do:**
1. Bind the `$ctrl.message` property in the markup to the instance of the controller that we know starts.

Normally, I would ask my question after providing code, however there's a good bit of code required to reproduce this problem (it's below, sans some AngularJS boilerplate.)  As that's the case, though, here's my **question:**

*In what way can I get the modals being spun off by this service to properly bind their contents to their given controller?*

**What I've tried:**
As you can see in `ModalService.bindModalDiv`, I've tried a few avenues of thought, mostly using `$compile`.  Yet, `$compile` and the resulting link function don't actually seem to be binding the new DOM elements to Angular.

I've tried using `$controller` to explicitly bind the new scope being generated to the `someModalCtrl` being instantiated, but that doesn't seem to help at all.

Because I can hit breakpoints on the `someModalCtrl`, and see the `console.log` message I used as a sanity check, I think I'm misunderstanding how exactly I'm supposed to bind the new DOM elements to Angular.  I'm sure I'm missing something basic that I've managed to forget about or disregard, somehow.

**One more note:**
I'm sure my problems with getting the modal to bind to AngularJS properly aren't the only problems present.   Please remember, I'm doing this partially as a learning excersize; if y'all can help me figure out my modal problem, I'll keep on doing my due diligence and hunting down the flaws I've doubtless built into this approach.  Therefore, **if you see something that's not a modal problem, it's OK to draw my attention to it, but I won't rewrite the question to fix whatever you find - unless it's absolutely essential that I do.**  As an example - I know that `ModalService.open` has some issues in how I'm implementing the promise setup.  A `$rootScope.$watch` is probably more reasonable.

**modalSvc.ts:**

```
export interface IModalSpecObject {
    parent?: string | Element | JQuery;
    templateURL: string
    controller: string;
    controllerAs?: string;
    data: object;
}

export class ModalInstance {
    public isOpen: boolean = true;
    public returnData: object = null;
    public element: JQLite = null;
    public $parent: JQuery = null;

    public constructor(
        public specObject: IModalSpecObject
    ) {
    }

    public close(returnData: object): void {
        if (this.element)
            this.element.remove();

        this.isOpen = false;
        this.returnData = returnData;
    }
}

export class ModalService {
    public pollRate: number = 250;
    public instance: ModalInstance = null;

    public static $inject: string[] = [
        '$q', '$rootScope', '$compile', '$controller'
    ];
    public constructor(
        public $q: ng.IQService,
        public $rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService,
        public $compile: ng.ICompileService,
        public $controller: ng.IControllerService
    ) {
    }

    public open(specObject: IModalSpecObject): ng.IPromise<{}> {
        if (this.instance && this.instance.isOpen)
            this.instance.close(null);

        this.instance = new ModalInstance(specObject);

        const $parent: JQuery = this.setParent(specObject);
        const modalDiv: JQLite = this.buildModal(specObject);            
        this.bindModalDiv(modalDiv, $parent); 

        const result: ng.IPromise<{}> = this.$q((resolve) => {
            setInterval(() => {
                if (!this.instance.isOpen) {
                    resolve(this.instance.returnData);
                }
            }, this.pollRate);
        });
        return result;
    }

    private buildModal(specObject: IModalSpecObject): JQLite {
        const modalDiv: JQLite = angular.element('<div/>');
        modalDiv.addClass('modal');
        const $modalPanel: JQuery = $('<div/>');
        $modalPanel.addClass('modal-panel');

        // Inject HTML template...
        $modalPanel.load(specObject.templateUrl);

        // Set up the angular controller...
        const controllerAs: string = specObject.controllerAs 
            ? specObject.controllerAs 
            : '$ctrl';
        $modalPanel.attr('ng-controller', `${specObject.controller} as ${controllerAs}`);
        modalDiv.append($modalPanel);

        this.instance.element = modalDiv;
        return modalDiv;
    }

    private setParent(specObject: IModalSpecObject): JQuery {
        let $parent: JQuery;
        if(!specObject.parent)
            $parent = $(document);
        else if (typeof specObject.parent === "string"
                 || specObject.parent instanceof Element)
            $parent = $(specObject.parent);
        else if (specObject.parent instanceof jQuery)
            $parent = specObject.parent;
        else
            $parent = $(document);

        this.instance.$parent = $parent;
        return $parent;
    }

    // !!!! !!!! I suspect this is where my problems lie. !!!! !!!!
    private bindModalDiv(modalDiv: JQLite, $parent: JQuery): void {
        const newScope: ng.IScope = this.$rootScope.$new(true);

        // Try #1: Bind generated element to parent...
        //$parent.append(this.$compile(modalDiv)(newScope));

        // Try #1a: Generate bindings, then append to parent...
        //const element: JQLite = this.$compile(modalDiv)(newScope);
        //$parent.append(element);

        // Try #2: Bind element to parent, then generate ng bindings...
        //$parent.append(modalDiv);
        //this.$compile(modalDiv)(newScope);

        // Try #3: Well, what if we bind a controller to the scope?
        const specObject: IModalSpecObject = this.instance.specObject;
        const controllerAs: string = specObject.controllerAs 
            ? specObject.controllerAs 
            : '$ctrl';
        this.$controller(`${specObject.controller} as ${controllerAs}`, {
            '$scope': newScope
        });

        const element = this.$compile(modalDiv)(newScope);
        $parent.append(element);
    }
}

angular
    .module('app')
    .service('modalSvc', ModalService);
```

**SomeController.ts:**
`SomeController.ts` pretty much just controls a button to trigger the modal's appearance; I've not included the markup for that reason.

```
export class SomeController {
    public static $inject: string[] = [ 'modalSvc' ];
    public constructor(
        public modalSvc: ModalService
    ) {
    }

    public $onInit(): void {
    }

    public openModal(): void {
        const newModal: IModalSpecObject = {
            parent: 'body',
            templateUrl: '/someModal.html',
            controller: 'someModalCtrl',
            data: {
                'message': 'You should see this.'
            }
        };

        this.modalSvc.open(newModal)
            .then(() => {
                console.log('You did it!');
            });
    }
}

angular.module('app').controller('someCtrl', SomeController);
```

**someModal.html:**

```
<div class="modal-header">
    Important Message
</div>    

<!-- This should read, "You should see this." -->
<div class="modal-body">
    {{ $ctrl.message }}
</div>

<!-- You should click this, and hit a breakpoint and/or close the modal. -->
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button ng-click="$ctrl.close()">Close</button>
</div>
```

**someModal.ts:**

```
export class SomeModalController {
    public message: string = '';

    public static $inject: string[] = [ 'modalSvc' ];
    public constructor(
        public modalSvc: ModalService
    ) {
    }

    public $onInit(): void {
        console.log('$onInit was triggered!');
        this.message = this.modalSvc.instance.specObject.data['message'];
    }

    public close(): void {
        this.modalSvc.instance.close(null);
    }
}

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('someModalCtrl', SomeModalController);
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out where I went wrong - I needed to use `$().load()`'s callback.  JQuery `load` is asynchronous, which meant that `$compile` was working correctly; however, the HTML in my modal partial wasn't loaded by the time `$compile` had done its job, thus the unbound HTML.

A slight modification of my `ModalService` got around this, though.

**Revised fragment of ModalSvc.ts:**

```
// This is just a convenience alias for void functions.  Included for completeness.
export type VoidFunction = () => void;

// ...

public open(specObject: IModalSpecObject): ng.IPromise<{}> {
    if (this.instance && this.instance.isOpen)
        this.instance.close(null);

    this.instance = new ModalInstance(specObject);

    const $parent: JQuery = this.setParent(specObject);
    // open already returned a promise before, we just needed to return
    // the promise from build modal, which in turn sets up the true
    // promise to resolve.
    return this.buildModal(specObject)
        .then((modalDiv: JQLite) => {
            this.bindModalDiv(modalDiv, $parent);

            const result: ng.IPromise<{}> = this.$q((resolve) => {
                // Also, side-note: to avoid resource leaks, always make sure
                // with these sorts of ephemeral watches to capture and release
                // them.  Resource leaks are _no fun_!
                const unregister: VoidFunction = this.$rootScope.$watch(() => {
                    this.instance.isOpen
                }, () => {
                    if (! this.instance.isOpen) {
                        resolve(this.instance.returnData);
                        unregister();
                    }
                });
            });
            return result;
       });
}

private buildModal(specObject: IModalSpecObject): ng.IPromise<{}> {
    const modalDiv: JQLite = angular.element('<div/>');
    modalDiv.addClass('modal');
    this.instance.element = modalDiv;

    const $modalPanel: JQuery = $('<div/>');
    $modalPanel.addClass('modal-panel');

    // By wrapping $modalPanel.load in a $q promise, we can
    // ensure that the modal is fully-built before we $compile it.
    const result: ng.IPromise<{}> = this.$q((resolve, reject) => {
        $modalPanel.load(specObject.templateUrl, () => {
            modalDiv.append($modalPanel);
            resolve(modalDiv);
        });
    });
    return result;
}

private setParent(specObject: IModalSpecObject): JQuery {
    let $parent: JQuery;
    if(!specObject.parent)
        $parent = $(document);
    else if (typeof specObject.parent === "string"
             || specObject.parent instanceof Element)
        $parent = $(specObject.parent);
    else if (specObject.parent instanceof jQuery)
        $parent = specObject.parent;
    else
        $parent = $(document);

    this.instance.$parent = $parent;
    return $parent;
}

private bindModalDiv(modalDiv: JQLite, parent: JQLite): void {
    // parent should be a JQLite so I can use the injector() on it.
    parent.injector().invoke(['$rootScope', '$compile', ($rootScope, $compile) => {
        const newScope: ng.IScope = $rootScope.$new(true);
        this.$controller(this.getControllerAsString(), {
            '$scope': newScope
        });
        const element: JQLite = $compile(modalDiv)(newScope);
        parent.append(element);
    }]);
}

private getControllerAsString(): string {
    const specObject: IModalSpecObject = this.instance.specObject;
    const controllerAs: string = specObject.controllerAs 
        ? specObject.controllerAs 
        : '$ctrl';

    return `${specObject.controller} as ${controllerAs}`;
}
```

I figured this out by going back and doing the step-by-step engineering.  I first ensured that `$compile` was working by creating an element whose contents were `{{ 2 + 2 }}`, compiling it, then injecting it.  When I saw `4` added to my page, I knew that the compile-then-inject aspect of the program worked just fine.

From there, I started building up the modal's construction, and found it working flawlessly...up until I got to jQuery `load`.  When I read the documentation, I saw the error of my ways.

**TL;DR:** Read the friendly manual!